# Can't open sharepoint designer 2010 when using Basic authentication over a non-SSL connection

Tags: sharepoint-designer, security

I have a sharepoint site and we have to have basic authentication set for users to have access.
But now when i go to open up a site in SP 2010 to do some work  i get the error and get transferred to an MS site saying

**You cannot open Office file types directly from a server that supports only Basic authentication over a non-SSL connection**

Any fix for this. MS this use to work with SP 2007!!!!

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

By default file operations that use Basic authentication over a non-SSL HTTP connection are disable in Office 2010 application (that means for SP Server too).
You can try to enable the SSL encryption on your server because by default the Basi auth works only over an SSL connection.

For other information: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2123563#FixItForMeAlways

Comment: thanks.
to enable ssl on the SP server means i would have to issue a certificate :(
Is there a way to avoid this to make it work?

Comment: You can do that without a certification. Take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3865039/https-connection-without-ssl-certificate

Answer (score 0):

You can extend your web application to a different set of authentication mode, say standard NTLM, don't expose it to user.
Then you can use this extended web application to design with SharePoint Designer.